# Abelian $\operatorname{Hom}(-,X)$ in $\mathcal{Alg}_{R/A}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

How do I find all objects $X$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(-,X)$ is an abelian group in the category $\mathcal{Alg}_{R/A}$ of algebras over a fixed $R-$algebra $A$?

I have been considering what being over $A$ induces, but am making no progress right now. The claim is that they are all of the form $A\ltimes M$ for $M$ an $A-$module.

Comment: Do you want the group structure to be natural?

Comment: When $A\ltimes M\to A$ is considered as an abelian group object, how do you retrieve $M$? Once you work that out, you should be able to extract a module $M_X$ from any abelian group object $X\to A$ such that $A \ltimes M_X \to A$ is the object $X\to A$ you started from.